# Как лучше всего бороться с дубликатами?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть база контактов. Как лучше всего при добавлении контакта проверять нет ли похожих данных в таблице? Просто делать аякс запрос каждый раз при введении нового символа будет накладно? Может быть есть готовый гем для такого случая?

Comment: А зачем при введении каждого символа? Сделайте при попытке сохранения. Или например при введении трех-пяти символов возвращайте аяксом все занятые ники начинающиеся на них, чтоб дальше уже без всяких запросов на клиенте сравнивать. Кучу вариантов можно придумать

Comment: Ну, готовый гем же тоже должен как-то работать, верно? :) Я бы скорее задумался о валидации с debouncing событий редактирования формы (а-ля если после нажатия в течение секунды форму не трогали).

Comment: Валидацию только при сохранении я отбросил по причине того что полей не мало и заполнив всё узнать что такая запись есть, не очень приятно. Проверять после каждого символа нужно (как мне кажется) т.к. много данных за несколько лет которые никто никогда не структурировал и из разных источников в том числе после телефонных переговоров в которых высока вероятность ошибки в написании фамилии или почты и нужно при введении как можно больше похожих вариантов предоставлять, вдруг будут неявные дубликаты. Вот и подумал может есть «бест практис» для такого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делать запрос к серверу на каждый символ не только накладно, но и бесполезно — если пользователь знает, что пишет, то делать запрос посередине "серии ввода" (последовательности нажатий с малым промежутком) смысла мало, пользователь просто не успеет посмотреть на результат, когда будет совершаться очередной запрос.

Решение: **debouncing**. Работает оно (для задержки в 1 с до запроса) примерно следующим образом:

```
полсекунды на деление
__X____X____*____R____X____X____X____*____R____*____*____*____X____X____*____R
0.0  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5  2.0  2.5  0.0  0.0   0.5 1.0

    X | изменение в форме
число | значение таймера после последнего изменения в форме
    R | запрос
```

Словами: оно ждёт после последнего изменения формы одну секунду и совершает запрос. Если во время хода таймера было совершено изменение, таймер обнуляется и идёт заново. Как следствие, запросы будут делаться не чаще раза в секунду.

- [Живой пример](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/)
- [Реализация для jQuery (`jquery-throttle-debounce`)](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce)